# Web fonts clickable area overlap when using smaller line height

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I have been trying to use a Neue Helvetica Thai Light webfont for a vertical menu. Letters in this menu are supposed to be large but space between lines is not. So I have set `font-size` and `line-height` in css and appereance is perfect but functionality is not.

Each link is extending above and below the letters so that neighboring items clickable areas overlap preventing the user to follow a link on which they have clicked. This problem is non extistant when using usual fonts like Arial, Verdana etc.

The problem is probably in the font itself but how can it be avoided, is there some workaround? I have sent question to the fonts.com - website that provided the font but still waiting for an answer.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu a {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW31-Light';
    font-size: 39px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: I waited about two weeks for a reply from them to a question about one of the webfonts looking awful at very large sizes on Windows! They did reply eventually though and were helpful.

Comment: I would assume the line height is the issue, i know you said you set it but try setting it at least the same pixel size as the font, i.e if the `font-size` is 39px, add the line-height as 39px.. alternatively provide a link to your page and i will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further (re)search on the Internet I have stumbled upon [this post](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/4386/trouble-with-clickable-area-and-small-line-height/p1#Item_14) and ended up using a slightly modified version of provided solution. Im not keen on answering my own question but it might be helpful for someone since this issue is not so common and so the answer(s) are not easy to find.

The trick is to hide overflowing part of the anchor. Since inline elements like anchors ignore `overflow` property anchor display is changed to `display: block`, and then set `overflow: hidden`. Afterwards adjust `height` so that the letters are not cut off. Use letters that go below baseline the most in your font since bottom part should be cut off first, for Helvetica small leter *g* was used.

```css
ul.menu a {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueW31-Light';
    font-size: 39px;
    display: block;
    height: 47px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLjvo3jp/) with the solution.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a hack for something that shouldn't need it.. would love to have a look at your page and see if there is a simpler method

Comment: @DannyHearnah thanks for offering your help. I have tried to use larger value for `line-height` but the issue is the same. Page is offline but nevertheless using links [is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126000) [discuraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89309) on SO, and using jsfiddle is not the option since font is proprietary and when using usual fonts the problem is not there. I have added an answer that is satisfying for me but there may be other approaches. If you find cleaner solution please do post it Id be happy to upvote it and accept it.

Comment: using links is discouraged you're right however the reason i asked for a link was purely because of the font not being a standard webfont.

Comment: @DannyHearnah I undestand. This problem is not isolated to this single font. For example there is a Neuton font freely [available](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/neuton) that has the same [problem](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/8/line-height-issues-with-web-font/p1). You can use it locally with code provided in the question.

Comment: @Bula I encountered this problem with just divs and standard fonts and your solution was perfect for me. I encourage you to accept it as the answer and potentially generalize the question to concern any overflowing text area beyond the line-height

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but perhaps something like  `font-height: 24px;` might help ?

Comment: Thanks, but there is no `font-height` property in css.

Comment: You are right, I could have sworn there was tho. My bad. How about using font-size with a px value instead of pt, like: font-size: 24px; ?

Comment: Im already using px, but its the same behavior, with pt and with px.